# No reply string using FTPSClient

Tags: javascript, android, ftps

when I use the this code, my app connect to the server, but I get no reply string. When I connect with a ftp client I can see the messages.

Code:

```
FTPSClient ftp = new FTPSClient("TLS",false);
try{
    Log.d("DEBUG","CONNECT TO SERVER");
    ftp.connect("domain.com");
    Log.d("DEBUG",ftp.getReplyString());
    if(FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
        Log.d("DEBUG","CONNECTED");
    }
} catch (SocketException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

The logcat output:

```
09-14 00:29:41.411 8571-8632/com.google.observer D/DEBUG: CONNECT TO SERVER
09-14 00:29:41.471 8571-8636/com.google.observer D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
09-14 00:29:41.741 8571-8636/com.google.observer D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7fa247a178
09-14 00:29:41.741 8571-8636/com.google.observer I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4

                                                                   [ 09-14 00:29:41.741  8571: 8636 D/         ]
                                                                   ro.exynos.dss isEnabled: 0
09-14 00:29:41.741 8571-8636/com.google.observer D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
09-14 00:29:41.761 8571-8571/com.google.observer I/InjectionManager: dispatchCreateOptionsMenu :com.google.observer.MainActivity
09-14 00:29:41.761 8571-8571/com.google.observer I/InjectionManager: dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :com.google.observer.MainActivity
09-14 00:29:41.761 8571-8571/com.google.observer D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
09-14 00:29:41.771 8571-8636/com.google.observer D/libGLESv1: DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : com.google.observer
09-14 00:29:41.791 8571-8571/com.google.observer I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@dd550b7 time:149560238
09-14 00:29:42.251 8571-8632/com.google.observer D/DEBUG: CONNECTED
```

Where is my reply string?

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays.toString(ftp.getReplyStrings())
```

Was the solution. Now I get the Server repleys